# I need help to capture a mulitiline text in a configuration using Powershell and Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to capture from the line switchport trunk native vlan 250 to the end where the ! mark is and then write another search pattern to find if any access port is used in this interface

```
interface fa0/1
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 250
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 48-52,54,64,66,68,70,74,76,80,82,84,86,88,96,98
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 104,106,112,128,144,148,150,178,182,184,186
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 192,194,199,250
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
 spanning-tree portfast trunk
!
```

I wrote a powershell function and use Regex statement below to find any switchport trunk native vlan 1 or other is found.  if it found, then I want to find out if the switchport mode access is configured in this interface.

```
$String="switchport\strunk\snative\svlan\s((?!1)|1)"
```

In powershell, I wrote

```
$Access_Port =  Select-String -Path $File -Pattern $String
```

Run this code, it found the switchport trunk native vlan 1 but it does not include the rest of line until the ! mark.

Comment: is the text shown the EXACT and ENTIRE content of the item? is it a capture from a utility or from a powershell cmdlet? how is the item stored - a $var containing a multiline string, a text file, or some other source?

Comment: another point - you have shown the input ... what is the EXACT output desired from that input?

Answer (score 0):

the following regex will capture all lines:

```
switchport trunk native vlan 250((.*\n))+
```

I tested it in https://regex101.com

You can use the following regex to match a who
le line that contains or does not contain specific word

```
^(?=.*?\bmust-have\b)(?=.*?\bmandatory\b)((?!avoid|illegal).)*$
```

You can further refer to:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a solution that does not use regular expressions?

```
$sr = New-Object System.IO.StringReader @'
interface fa0/1
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 250
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 48-52,54,64,66,68,70,74,76,80,82,84,86,88,96,98
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 104,106,112,128,144,148,150,178,182,184,186
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 192,194,199,250
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
 spanning-tree portfast trunk
!
'@
while( ($s = $sr.ReadLine()) ) {
  if( $s.TrimStart().StartsWith('switchport trunk native vlan') ) {
    while( ($s = $sr.ReadLine()) -and $s.Trim() -ne '!' ) { 
      if( $s.TrimStart().StartsWith('switchport trunk allowed vlan') ) {
        $p = (-split $s)[-1] -split ','
        Write-Host '$p type is', $p.GetType().FullName, '; $p contains', $p.Length, "elements: ${p}"
      }
    }
  }
}
$sr.Dispose()
```

**Output**

```
$p type is System.String[] ; $p contains 15 elements: 48-52 54 64 66 68 70 74 76 80 82 84 86 88 96 98
$p type is System.String[] ; $p contains 11 elements: 104 106 112 128 144 148 150 178 182 184 186
$p type is System.String[] ; $p contains 4 elements: 192 194 199 250
```